# Mass-Edit records in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: api, oauth, google-apps

Mass-Editing data in Salesforce is a pain. And even if tools like AppBuddy make this less click-intensive, none comes close to Excel or Google Spreadsheet.

So I was just thinking if one could push data into an empty Google Spreadsheet, let people edit it there and then synch the changes back to Salesforce.com.

It took me seconds to find and install the Google Data Toolkit for Salesforce. But it seems this is not working anymore. Every request to Google servers return with

> The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was
>   requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed
>   request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you
>   received this message to inform them of the error. A detailed error
>   message follows:
>
> The site "http://force.com" has not been registered.

After googleing for a while my impression is, that this Toolkit is old and Google switched authentication to Oauth.

1. **Isn't this something Salesforce also uses / understands or will
   understand when "Identitiy" is released?**
2. **Is it true that there is no update or alternative to that outdated toolkit?**

Comment: I've heard some awesome gossip about Google Apps in general and the Force.com Platform but more in the Heroku / Database.com area, not (yet) for regular Salesforce. Fingers crossed, "safe harbor", blah blah blah... In the meantime you might want to try out the Excel Connector plugin? http://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/ (no, I'm not related to the author)

Comment: See also 'Integrating Google Apps with Salesforce using Google Apps Script' http://youtu.be/9SEAmNDtlcA

Comment: Very cool, Pat ;-) Thanks for this hint. Do you also know a way to do things the other way round? I want my user to select records in Salesforce, click a button and then a tmp spreadsheet with this records opens in Google drive. The user mass-edits everything there and clicks save and the changes are magically synched to Salesforce.

Comment: Along the lines of metadaddy's post, here's a script which "connects and fetches data from Salesforce" using OAuth. I think I've seen a similar script for writing back to Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, SFDC supports OAuth today. I'm an integration noob, and certainly don't know the vaguaries of writing extensions to google apps, but at least in theory, we can support that OAuth request from google today.

For the second, I don't know the history, but (as most community toolkits are), it is opensource on code.google.com. The code timestamps for the most recent files are quite old (pushing two years), which might even predate OAuth going GA. At the very least it was in its infancy in the platform. So there might be enough to go on to build your own.

The source can be found at: 
http://code.google.com/p/apex-google-data/source/browse